# How do I pass in values to AWS CDK at deploy time?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cdk

How do I pass in values to AWS CDK at **`deploy`** time (not `synth` time)?

I can see that I can retrieve context values within an App:

```
(String)app.getNode().tryGetContext("keyOfMyValue");
```

The example above is from the [Java API](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/latest/java/index.html?software/amazon/awscdk/services/codedeploy/ServerApplication.Builder.html) and returns a string where the key value pair was passed using `-c keyOfMyValue=someValue`.  This value is then passed to `cdk synth`.

Whilst the CLI help for `cdk deploy` shows an identical `Context` parameter, I don't see how to access that within a Stack.  I specifically don't want to have all values defined at the time of synthesis, I want to pass some simple values (e.g. strings) to CDK at deploy time.

Is there an example of how to do this?

Comment: As far as i know Context is the place to locate these variables, however, in my project i have used ssm in order to store parameters and read them on deploy. Let me know if you would like further information about this solution.

Answer (score 5):

This snippet will be in .NET but I assume that you can do something similar in Java. Assuming your stack is named `astack` ...

You can gather the context value with

```
cdk deploy astack -c environment=prod
```

```cs
var app = new App();
var environment = app.Node.TryGetContext("environment")?.ToString() ?? "dev";
```

make a class and interface...

```cs
public interface IAStackProps : IStackProps
{
    public string Environment { get; set; }
}

public class AStackProps : StackProps, IAStackProps
{
    public string Environment { get; set; }
}
```

pass it with...

```cs
new AStack(app, stackName, new AStackProps {
    Environment = environment,
    ...
});
```

then you can access it in your stack.

```cs
public AStack(Construct scope, string id, IAStackProps props = null) : 
    base(scope, id, props)
{
    // props.Environment
```

Answer (score 1):

Stack is a child of Construct (as App), so - the same way, I guess:

```
this.getNode().tryGetContext()
```

Answer (score 1):

Passing deploy-time parameters is done with the combination of a) creating CloudFormation template parameters using `CfnParameter` class, and then b) passing their values with "*--parameters*" argument of the `cdk deploy` command. Details at https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/latest/guide/parameters.html.

It's worth nothing that "*--context*" parameters - the synth-time parameters, may still be passed with `cdk deploy`, because "cdk deploy" runs "cdk synth" implicitly.